# nonce too low , please help

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions

please help, I have 1 transaction stuck 7 days,  I have sent 1 transaction with 0 ETH and nonce to the same address, to cancel the stuck transaction but all the nonce too low error, looking forward to help help, thanks

[image]i.stack.imgur.com/Kuh7a.png

Comment: To replace stuck transaction you have to resubmit it with same nonce and higher price. Probably the software clients ( which you are using to achieve that ) do not support transaction replacement. You should look for another transaction sending software or try to resubmit the transaction by coding.

Comment: Thank you very much, I traded on MEW and tried to cancel the transaction but it was unsuccessful, followed the instructions on MEW but got a nonce too low error, hope someone can help me.

Comment: Tried sending another transaction with a higher price and same nonce but all failed with a nonce too low error

Comment: @chupika Depending on the provider usually the require gas price to increase at least 10%.

Comment: I raised the gas price by 50% and still the error

Comment: help me, help me......

Comment: Could you ever figure this out? I'm the same situation as you